# PLINQ Aggregate exception I don't understand

Tags: c#, exception, plinq

I was waching the PLINQ PCD09 presentation by Igor Ostrovsky, and wanted to try to see what I could get out of my CULV laptop.

At a point I got a strange exception and I'm not sure what it means. I've condensed the code for better overview. It is the last primes.Sum() that causes the exception and if I make the range small - 8000 - the exception is not thrown. Any ideas?

```
Func<int, bool> isprime = n => // ignore input checks for now
    {
        int sqr = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(Math.Sqrt(n)));
        for (int i = 2; i < sqr; i++) if (n % i == 0) return false;
        return true;
    };

var numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 8*1000*1000);
long counter = 0;
ParallelQuery<int> primes = numbers.AsParallel().Where(x => isprime(x));
counter = primes.Sum();
```

Exception (quite long)

> System.AggregateException was
>   unhandled   Message=One or more errors
>   occurred.   Source=System.Core
>   StackTrace:
>          at System.Linq.Parallel.QueryTaskGroupState.QueryEnd(Boolean
>   userInitiatedDispose)
>          at System.Linq.Parallel.SpoolingTask.SpoolStopAndGo[TInputOutput,TIgnoreKey](QueryTaskGroupState
>   groupState, PartitionedStream`2
>   partitions, SynchronousChannel`1[]
>   channels, TaskScheduler taskScheduler)
>          at System.Linq.Parallel.DefaultMergeHelper`2.System.Linq.Parallel.IMergeHelper<TInputOutput>.Execute()
>          at System.Linq.Parallel.MergeExecutor`1.Execute[TKey](PartitionedStream`2
>   partitions, Boolean ignoreOutput,
>   ParallelMergeOptions options,
>   TaskScheduler taskScheduler, Boolean
>   isOrdered, CancellationState
>   cancellationState, Int32 queryId)
>          at System.Linq.Parallel.PartitionedStreamMerger`1.Receive[TKey](PartitionedStream`2
>   partitionedStream)
>          at System.Linq.Parallel.InlinedAggregationOperator`3.WrapPartitionedStream[TKey](PartitionedStream`2
>   inputStream,
>   IPartitionedStreamRecipient`1
>   recipient, Boolean preferStriping,
>   QuerySettings settings)
>          at System.Linq.Parallel.UnaryQueryOperator`2.UnaryQueryOperatorResults.ChildResultsRecipient.Receive[TKey](PartitionedStream`2
>   inputStream)
>          at System.Linq.Parallel.WhereQueryOperator`1.WrapPartitionedStream[TKey](PartitionedStream`2
>   inputStream,
>   IPartitionedStreamRecipient`1
>   recipient, Boolean preferStriping,
>   QuerySettings settings)
>          at System.Linq.Parallel.UnaryQueryOperator`2.UnaryQueryOperatorResults.ChildResultsRecipient.Receive[TKey](PartitionedStream`2
>   inputStream)
>          at System.Linq.Parallel.ScanQueryOperator`1.ScanEnumerableQueryOperatorResults.GivePartitionedStream(IPartitionedStreamRecipient`1
>   recipient)
>          at System.Linq.Parallel.UnaryQueryOperator`2.UnaryQueryOperatorResults.GivePartitionedStream(IPartitionedStreamRecipient`1
>   recipient)
>          at System.Linq.Parallel.UnaryQueryOperator`2.UnaryQueryOperatorResults.GivePartitionedStream(IPartitionedStreamRecipient`1
>   recipient)
>          at System.Linq.Parallel.QueryOperator`1.GetOpenedEnumerator(Nullable`1
>   mergeOptions, Boolean suppressOrder,
>   Boolean forEffect, QuerySettings
>   querySettings)
>          at System.Linq.Parallel.QueryOpeningEnumerator`1.OpenQuery()
>          at System.Linq.Parallel.QueryOpeningEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
>          at System.Linq.Parallel.IntSumAggregationOperator.InternalAggregate(Exception&
>   singularExceptionToThrow)
>          at System.Linq.Parallel.InlinedAggregationOperator`3.Aggregate()
>          at System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.Sum(ParallelQuery`1
>   source)
>          at ConsoleTest.TestClass.Test() in C:\Users\henrik\Documents\Visual
>   Studio
>   2010\Projects\CSharp\ConsoleTest\ConsoleTest\TestClass.cs:line
>   23
>          at ConsoleTest.Program.Main(String[]
>   args) in
>   C:\Users\henrik\Documents\Visual
>   Studio
>   2010\Projects\CSharp\ConsoleTest\ConsoleTest\Program.cs:line
>   20
>          at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly
>   assembly, String[] args)
>          at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String
>   assemblyFile, Evidence
>   assemblySecurity, String[] args)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object
>   state)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback
>   callback, Object state, Boolean
>   ignoreSyncCtx)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback
>   callback, Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
>   InnerException:
>   System.OverflowException
>          Message=Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.
>          Source=System.Core
>          StackTrace:
>               at System.Linq.Parallel.IntSumAggregationOperator.IntSumAggregationOperatorEnumerator`1.MoveNextCore(Int32&
>   currentElement)
>               at System.Linq.Parallel.InlinedAggregationOperatorEnumerator`1.MoveNext(TIntermediate&
>   currentElement, Int32& currentKey)
>               at System.Linq.Parallel.StopAndGoSpoolingTask`2.SpoolingWork()
>               at System.Linq.Parallel.SpoolingTaskBase.Work()
>               at System.Linq.Parallel.QueryTask.BaseWork(Object
>   unused)
>               at System.Linq.Parallel.QueryTask.<.cctor>b__0(Object
>   o)
>               at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
>               at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
>          InnerException:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you remove call to AsParallel() then you can see that Enumerable.Sum throws and OverflowException. Changing Sum() to Sum(x => (long)x) should help.

Comment: You are right. Now I'm a little surprised to find out that adding this : var numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 8 * 1000 * 1000).Cast<long>(); is not enough. The internal Sum representation must be an int.. Thanks for you help. –

Comment: Even though I didn't have the same error, it did help me solve my problem... so +1 from me.